# Best way to implementing a tabbed page

Tags: html, http, jsp

I am developing a web application using jsp , struts framework and i have to develop 4 different pages. In each page it will be present a horizontal tab menu.I do not have a lot of expertize in web development. So i ask what should be the best way to the develop this feature.
 1) Use one iframe to display one of the four different pages , i would have a tab menu and each time i click in a different tab it will reload the iframe.
 2) each time i click in a tab it reloads the full page.
The second question that i make is : how can i store the values inserted in the last tab ?
For example : If i have two tab like this :

> ```
>     <ul id="tablist">
>      <li><a class="current" href="/action1">Tab0</a></li>
>      <li><a href="/action2">Tab1</a></li>
>    </ul>
> ```
>
> Each time i click in one tab i will lose all the data inserted in the page ?
>   The data is only sent if is inside a form element , correct ?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use client side (javascript) tab handling.

Populate all the tabs with data and make only one tab visible at a time.
There are bunch of javascript tab libs out there.
One of them is this
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/